# Creating multiple summary tables with one function in R

Tags: r, apply, summary

I couldn't find an answer to this specific question sorry if it's been asked:

```
library(tidyverse)
#sampledata
df <- data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 v1=c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 v2=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 v3=c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1))
```

I want to find the number of "1"s and "0"s in each v1, v2, v3 for each level of "group".
Currently I have been using

```
table(df$group, df$v1) 
table(df$group, df$v2)
table(df$group, df$v3)
```

ad nauseum to get the number of "1" in each variable but I can't figure out how to create many such tables with one function...Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to apply the same function to multiple columns.

```
lapply(df[-1], function(x) table(df$group, x))

#$v1
#   x
#    0 1
#  0 1 3
#  1 2 2

#$v2
#   x
#    0 1
#  0 2 2
#  1 4 0

#$v3
#   x
#    0 1
#  0 1 3
#  1 2 2
```

---

Or with `dplyr` we can use `count`

```
purrr::map(names(df)[-1], ~count(df, group, !!sym(.x)))
```